# Why is React rendering my component over and over with an unchanged state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a simple scroll-to-top component and I thought that React will only re-render a component if something in it changes. Since I have a conditional tied to state in my render, shouldn't React only render it if the state changes? Instead, I'm seeing it re-render with every little scroll.

Also, if I left it as-is, are there any downsides to it re-rendering so much?

```
import React from 'react';
import './scroll-to-top.css';

export default class extends React.Component {

  state = {
    shouldShowButton: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    this.setState({
    shouldShowButton: window.scrollY > 250 ? true : false
  });
 }

  render () {
    {console.log("i have rendered!")}
    return (
      this.state.shouldShowButton ? <a className="scroll-to-top" href="#">Return to Top</a> : null
    );
  };
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Let's think through your code.

When the component loads, you're attaching a listener to the scroll event:

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
```

This fires `handleScroll` when the user scrolls. `handleScroll` sets the state of the component, regardless of whether or not the ternary condition resolves as true or false:

```
handleScroll = () => {
  this.setState({
    shouldShowButton: window.scrollY > 250 ? true : false
  });
}
```

Whenever we use `setState`, React triggers `render`. Hence, `render` is triggering with every little scroll.

Downsides - you should be really careful of attaching *anything* to `scroll`, as it can affect performance. You might consider debouncing the event if you really, really need to do so. (Where debouncing is the technique of rate-limiting how many times a function can be called.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. That makes sense now.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

This happens, because you are calling handleScroll function every time scroll event is fired. To fix this, setState only in condition:

```
import React from 'react';
import './scroll-to-top.css';

export default class extends React.Component {

  state = {
    shouldShowButton: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    const {shouldShowButton} = this.state;
    if (!shouldShowButton && window.scrollY > 250) {
       this.setState({
          shouldShowButton: true
       });
    } else if (shouldShowButton && window.scrollY <= 250) {
       this.setState({
          shouldShowButton: false
       });
    }
 }

  render () {
    {console.log("i have rendered!")}
    return (
      this.state.shouldShowButton ? <a className="scroll-to-top" href="#">Return to Top</a> : null
    );
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's typical for Component. It's re-rendered(not in DOM but in virtual DOM) each time `.setState` is called, `props` are changes or *parent element is re-rendered*. 
Just an example how re-rendering parent also fires re-rendering for child:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log('child re-rendered');
    return 'test';
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {a: 1};
    setInterval(() => this.setState(oldState => ({...oldState, a: oldState.a + 1})), 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
      <Child />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here you can check that child is re-rendered in the line as parent's `.setState` is called.

But it is not 100% to be issue for performance. Virtual DOM is much faster than browser DOM.

But if you want to avoid such a behavior you may use React.PureComponent instead of React.Component and then it will not be re-rendered on parent's update. Also PureComponent handles case when `.setState` does not actually changes value. 
So there will be less re-rendering.

Official docs are good enough but here is also [fine article at Medium](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/using-a-purecomponent-in-reacts-262972f9f1e0)